# What is the easist way to disable the cell selection of static UITableView in UITableViewController either in Storyboard or code

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I want to make "tableViewcell.selection = .None" , either by storyboard or code with minimum lines. I have tricks to do it, but I really willing to know if there is any other easiest possible way exist which I may missing in the apple documentation.
I am working with below components:-

1. UITableViewController
2. UITableView (Static)
3. UITableViewCell (no IBOutlet connected because its not required for my simple implementation)
4. Subviews of UITableView has IBOutlets
5. In .swift, didSelectForRowAtIndexPath defined because I want user interaction on click (no delegate method called because so far not required)

Is there any way to disable cell selection from storyboard.

Comment: You can set the userInteractionEnabled to false

Comment: @PGDev I need user interaction and handle click on cell.

Comment: You want your cell to be not selected when you tap on it right?

Comment: I want it to select but don't want to highlight the color. What I generally does in dynamic tableview is that I uses this code "customTableViewCell.selection = .None" in my cellForRowAtIndexPath , and it keep enables it select but without highlighting its background color. I want to do same in static tableview.

Comment: In the storyboard itself you have the property of cell selection. You can set it there for whichever cell you want.

Comment: @PGDev Yes it worked. I found myself as miss understood the concept between cell.selection and tableView.selection properties use in storyboard. May be long time back I have used in wrong way (means I was using tableView.selection instead of cellView ) and made my perception wrong.
your comment convinced me to try again, and it solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the **selection style** of cell to **None** in storyboard.

Refer this:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623221-selectionstyle